# When does binding target get updated for complex paths?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

When using databinding in WPF, the target dependency object gets updated when it is notified that the source has changed through the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

For example:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomeField}"/>
```

The text field will change to correctly reflect the value of SomeField whenever `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SomeField"))` is called from the source.

What if I use a complex path like the following:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomeObjField.AnotherField}"/>
```

Will the text field get updated for `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SomeObjField"))` on the source?

What about `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AnotherField"))` on the intermediate object (the object contained within the SomeObjField)?

Source objects and fields are NOT dependency objects or properties! Assume that the property/classes are implemented something like the following:

```
public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation...

   public string SomeField
   {
      get { return val; }
      set
      {
         val = value;
         // fire PropertyChanged()
      }
   }

   public SubData SomeObjField
   {
      get { return val; }
      set
      {
         val = value;
         // fire PropertyChanged()
      }
   }   
}

public class SubData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation...

   public string AnotherField
   {
      get { return val; }
      set
      {
         val = value;
         // fire PropertyChanged()
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further investigation, it appears that when any part of the complex path sends a change notification the binding is updated. Thus, if the source object OR the intermediate object is changed the binding will be updated.

I built a test project like Jared's:

```
<StackPanel Name="m_panel">
    <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Path=SomeObjField.AnotherField }"  />
    <TextBox x:Name="field1"/>
    <Button Click="Button1_Click">Edit Root Object</Button>
    <TextBox x:Name="field2"/>
    <Button Click="Button2_Click">Edit Sub Object</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

And the code behind:

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    m_panel.DataContext = new Data();
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Data d = m_panel.DataContext as Data;
    d.SomeObjField = new SubData(field1.Text);
}

private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Data d = m_panel.DataContext as Data;
    d.SomeObjField.AnotherField = field2.Text;
}
```

I am using the basic data implementation that I provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your asking with the PropertyChanged part of the question.  But if the properties involved are all DependencyProperty backed properties then this should work as expected.  I drew up the following example

Window1.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel Name="m_panel">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomeField}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomeField.AnotherField }"  />
        <Button Click="Button_Click">Update Root Object</Button>
        <Button Click="Button_Click_1">Update Another Field</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Window1.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_panel.DataContext = new Class1();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Class1)m_panel.DataContext).SomeField = new Class2();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Class1)m_panel.DataContext).SomeField.AnotherField = "Updated field";
    }
}
```

And the classes

```
public class Class1 : DependencyObject
{
    public static DependencyProperty SomeFieldProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SomeField",
        typeof(Class2),
        typeof(Class1));

    public Class2 SomeField
    {
        get { return (Class2)GetValue(SomeFieldProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SomeFieldProperty, value); }
    }

    public Class1()
    {
        SomeField = new Class2();
    }
}

public class Class2 : DependencyObject
{
    public static DependencyProperty AnotherFieldProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "AnotherField",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(Class2));

    public string AnotherField
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(AnotherFieldProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AnotherFieldProperty, value); }
    }

    public Class2()
    {
        AnotherField = "Default Value";
    }
}
```

Comment: Only the target property (TextBlock.Text in this case) can be assumed to be a dependency property. SomeField, SomeObjField, and AnotherField are not. If they were, there would be no need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I followed your example and created a simple test project. I was hoping someone would know the answer off of the top of their head.